# projects.set_current() returns EOFError: Ran out of input

Tags: brightway

I have a brightway project with a version of ecoinvent, biosphere3, and a foreground database. Usually,I can load this project without any problem with projects.set_current('myproject') but **from time to time** I get this error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-24-57b3d237167c>", line 1, in <module>
    bw.projects.set_current('Microalgae_2nd')

  File "C:\Users\GF20PZ\Miniconda3\envs\new_ab\lib\site-packages\bw2data\project.py", line 144, in set_current
    self._reset_meta()

  File "C:\Users\GF20PZ\Miniconda3\envs\new_ab\lib\site-packages\bw2data\project.py", line 169, in _reset_meta
    obj.__init__()

  File "C:\Users\GF20PZ\Miniconda3\envs\new_ab\lib\site-packages\bw2data\serialization.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.load()

  File "C:\Users\GF20PZ\Miniconda3\envs\new_ab\lib\site-packages\bw2data\serialization.py", line 127, in load
    self.data = self.deserialize()

  File "C:\Users\GF20PZ\Miniconda3\envs\new_ab\lib\site-packages\bw2data\serialization.py", line 240, in deserialize
    return self.unpack(pickle.load(open(self.filepath, "rb")))

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

And I can't access the project anymore and have to use a backup to start again until this error shows up again after having used the project a few times.
I can still see the project when I list them with  `bw.projects` .

Does anyone have an idea of where this comes from and why it only happens from time to time (still quite annoying though)?

**EDIT:**
Using `%debug` after the error message and  `print(self.filepath)` in jupyter notebook returns:
`C:\Users\GF20PZ\AppData\Local\pylca\Brightway3\Microalgae_2nd.6981ad8145d95aa4bc933b7aa86097ee\setups.pickle`

My code updates the calculation setups in the project but I sometimes have to stop the kernel while it's running (because I forgot something or so)
My guess is that the calculation setups get somehow corrupted if I do this...Could it be the case?
I should check if this happens only when I do so.

I don't need to recover my project now as I have a backup but I would like to know how this issue can be avoided.

Thank you very much,

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by file corruption or some other IO error reading one of the metadata files (which are stored as pickles). We can't tell which one from the error you pasted.

The following are stored as pickle files:

- Calculation setups
- Geomapping (i.e. location string to unique integer IDs)
- Preferences
- Dynamic setups (used only for temporalis, i.e. time-dependent LCA)

The behaviour you are seeing shouldn't happen, so it is hard to debug :) Are you sharing or syncing projects using something like Dropbox? Or do you have the same project open in multiple interpreter sessions or notebooks?

You can find out which file is causing the problem is you are using `ipython` or a `jupyter` notebook by entering debugging mode with `%debug`, and then printing `self.filepath`.

If you can figure out which file is causing the error, please update your answer, and maybe also post a link to the script or notebook which is creating the project.

Comment: Thank you Chris ! I just edited my question with what you asked for. My project is really built in the "classic" way so I don't think there is a need for sharing it now (bw.bw2setup()
, import ecoinvent with SingleOutputEcospold2Importer and built a foreground database "manually" with the activity browser. )
And no my project is only open in one spyder console.
BR, Pierre

Comment: It is the AB creating and manipulating these calculation setups, and either it has a bug or it is getting interrupted in the middle of a file write. In any case, you can fix this problem in the future by deleting that specific file. A new one will be created, but you will lose your existing setups.

Comment: Ok thank you. It's good to know. BR, Pierre